# How do I implement env vairables with a Vue front-end and a rails backe-end? Is it necissary to use the dotenv package to complete this task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, environment-variables

I started working on a project the has some API keys that need to be protected. My personal projects are all using React and Node, but this project is built using yarn (which I'm unfamiliar with). I have ran `yarn add dotenv` already, and I've tried using their documentation to get it up and running. All of the `console.log(process.env.***)` return `undefined`.

My method so far has been to add my variables to the .env file found in the root of the project, and add `require('dotenv').config()` to the project's `application.js` file to be loaded. I read that Vue.js 3 doesn't require dotenv and instead uses _VUE_APP  prepended to the variable name (which I've tried to make sure it doesn't work that way with Vue 2.8. Spoiler, it does not).

Is there a step I'm missing? Should I take a different approach altogether?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lets suppose you have two environments: *development* and *production*.

For having the variables for these environments, create one file for each environment in the root folder (where is the `package.json` or `.gitignore`), one file called `.env.development`and the other called `.env.development`, and then just create the variables there.

For example, let's say we want one environment variable called *api-path*, so create a variable in each file called *VUE_APP_API_PATH* (for example in development environment `VUE_APP_API_PATH = http://localhost:3000`).

Then, you can retrieve these environment values with `let API_route = process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT_API` in the script you need this value.

More info here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

Hope it helps.

Comment: I actually went through some other documentation with a colleague and found a great article that helped put all the pieces together. https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/586 This was the back-end config I was missing. Thanks again!